# c# detecting disconnect from server with timer

Tags: c#, tcp, packet

I have a client type application that is receiving packets from remote server.
Now and then it so happens that for some reason server disconnects me.
Sometimes there are some problems on my end ISP drops internet etc.

I have been trying to catch those exceptions and goog-ling for an answer but at the end every one
points to "make a timer and check periodically for received packets."

Now i have a function that is receiving all incoming traffic.
This function is executed every time packet is received.

Now my idea is to create a function that will create timer with let say 50 seconds time out.
This function will reset timer to 0 each time packet is received and restart it.

If timer reach 50 seconds it will throw an error "disconnected!" and some logic will follow
how to reconnect.

Now main problem i have is ... i can not "pause" my main packet receiving function. 
I have tried to make it in another thread but program keep recreating new threads , killing threads by ID is a bad practice and i haven't gone down that road ... yet.

Is this a how i should handle my problem or someone has a better idea?
Below is my packet receive function.

```
 public void OnReceive()
        {
           try
            {
               recv_pack = locSec.TrIncom();
                if (recv_pack != null)
                {
                    foreach (Packet packet in recv_pack)
                    {                     
                        byte[] packet_bytes = packet.GetBytes();

                        PacketHandler.HandlePacket(packet, locSec);
                        //here i would check for packet receive with timer                  
                        //CheckDisconnect();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch() 
            {}
        }
```

So far i have come up with this:

```
public bool CheckDisconnect()
{
    bool KeepGoing = true;

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 50 && KeepGoing; i++ )
    {
        Thead.Sleep(1000);

        if(i == 50)
        {
            KeepGoing = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected!");
            // ... starting reconnect procedure
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve? It seems like there might be a different approach that's possible.

Comment: What are you using? TCP? UDP? What higher-level networking package (it doesn't look like you're using raw sockets)?

Comment: As mentioned by @MichaelPerrenoud, this question seems to be an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - I strongly encourage you to describe the actual problem you are trying to solve with your application!

Comment: what do you mean by 'pause', up until that paragraph I was 100% with you (I have just written identical code - aka watchdog)

Comment: Let me be more specific. In Fortune 500 companies, where latency and success are paramount, we don't worry about knowing when a connection has timed out. What we're worried about is can we retry. Is the message persistent for retrying? How many times before true failure? How long between retries. I really think that's what you're trying to get to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understand completely, but if those two functions are in the same thread, can't you just make a global variable that controls the OnReceive() function and set it to false in your CheckDisconnect() function?

Comment: Now this was brilliant idea. Fixed my problem with 5 lines of code.